# Reiniciar lista numerada VBA Excel Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou a tentar criar uma macro em VBA para criar um documento de word a partir do Excel.

De momento estou a ter problemas com as listas.

Eu quero que a numeração das listas esteja ligado aos meus Estilos Header1 e Header2 de modo a ficarem assim:

```
1. Header1
  1.1. Header2
2. Header1
  2.1 Header2
```

O problema é que o nível 2 da lista não está a resetar mesmo quando utilizo a propriedade .ResetOnHigher

Isto significa que o resultado que obtenho se parece mais com:

```
1. Header1
  1.1. Header2
2. Header1
  1.2 Header2
```

Não sei se estou a fazer alguma coisa de errado ou se me falta algum pedaço de código aqui fica um excerto do código que estou a utilizar.

```
(...)

With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "%1."
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .StartAt = 1
End With

With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
    .NumberFormat = "%1.%2."
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .ResetOnHigher = 1
    .StartAt = 1
End With

    With myDoc
    'Heading 1
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Size = 24
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Color = wdColorBlack
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).Font.Bold = True
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 12
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading1).LinkToListTemplate _
            ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
            ListLevelNumber:=1

    'Heading 2
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading2).Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading2).Font.Size = 18
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading2).Font.Color = wdColorBlack
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading2).Font.Bold = True
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading2).ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading2).ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 12
        .Styles(wdStyleHeading2).LinkToListTemplate _
            ListTemplate:=ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
            ListLevelNumber:=2
End With

(...)

'Loop through sheets
For I = 2 To WS_Count - 1

'Check if sheet is to be included and if so past its content to word
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Shapes("Enable").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 = True Then

    'Insert Group Title if Group is different
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells(1, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value = False Then

        myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = myDoc.Styles("Heading 1")
        myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("A1")
        myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

    End If

    'Insert Page Title
    myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Style = myDoc.Styles("Heading 2")
    myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("A2")
    myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

    'Insert Tables
    Call ExcelRangeToWord(myDoc, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("range1"), 1)
    myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraph
    Call ExcelRangeToWord(myDoc, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("range2"), 2)
    myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraph

    'Insert Page Break on last paragraph
    myDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)

End If

(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente armazenar o ultimo *header* em uma variável e na hora de usar o comando `.ResetOnHigher` igualem com a variável

Ex:

```
Dim variavel as long
variavel = ultimoHeader.value(exemplo)

With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)

    .ResetOnHigher = variavel

end With
```

Answer (score -1):

```
'formato de encabezado.
objWord.Selection.Style = ("Heading 1")

'Crear pasos para dar numeración a titulo 1.1.

With objWord.ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "%1.%2"
End With          
    End With
    .LinkedStyle = "Heading 2"
    End With
```